# Trying to accurately get 100 digits of pi with Chudnovsky's algorithm in PYTHON

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, symbolic-math, pi

I am trying to teach myself Chudnovsky's algorithm using Python and this wikipedia page:

[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chudnovsky_algorithm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1Uht.png)

On the wiki, I am focused on the "high performance iterative implementation, [that] can be simplified to":

[image]

I tried to code up the equation on the far right that is using the Sigma symbol.  I am familiar with Python but am not that great at math.  The goal I set for myself is to see if I can accurately print out at least 100 digits of pi.

There are 5 sets of parentheses in the formula so I tried to code up each of the 5 different components.  I also wrote a function that does factorials because factorials are used in 3 of the 5 components/parentheses.

Here's my 23 lines of working code, can someone please help me understand why it does not ACCURATELY go to 100 digits?  It accurately goes to the 28th digit: 3.1415926535897932384626433832.  Then for the 29th digit it says 8 but it should be 7...

```
import math
from decimal import *

def factorial(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    memory = n
    
    for i in range(1, n):
        memory *= i
    
    return memory

iterations = 500
_sum = 0

#here's the Sigma part
for q in range(0, iterations):
    a = factorial(6*q)
    b = (545140134*q) + 13591409
       
    c = factorial(3*q)
    d = (factorial(q))**3
    e = (-262537412640768000)**q
    
    numerator = (a*b)
    denominator = (c*d*e)

    _sum += Decimal(numerator / denominator)

#ensures that you get 100 digits for pi
getcontext().prec = 100

sq = Decimal(10005).sqrt()
overPI = Decimal(426880 * sq)

pi = (overPI) * (Decimal(1 / _sum))
print("Pi is", pi)
```

Thank you for any assistance that you're able to provide.

Comment: Floats have limited precision. You should use `decimal`s only.

Comment: `_sum += float(numerator / denominator)` - you're limited to double-precision floating point's 16 d.p. or so of precision.

Comment: Ok, thank you for pointing this out!  I removed float and used Decimal.  It increased the accuracy to the 28th digit (instead of to the 17th digit).  How do I increase accuracy to the 100th digit and beyond?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Set the decimal precision at the *start* of the file so that it is applied to all subsequent operations:

  ```
  from decimal import *
  getcontext().prec = 100
  ```
- Convert either or both operands to `Decimal` before dividing or multiplying:

  ```
  # bad, float to decimal -> loss of precision
  _sum += Decimal(numerator / denominator)

  # better, precision preserved
  _sum += Decimal(numerator) / Decimal(denominator)
  ```

Result - accurate to 98 d.p. (100 s.f. minus rounding error):

```
#     3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751058209749445923078164062862089986280348253421170679
Pi is 3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974944592307816406286208998628034825342117069
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked!!  By the way, what does "d.p." and "s.f." stand for?  I tried Googling it but nothing came up that made sense.  Again, I appreciate your taking the time to point out what I was doing wrong.

Comment: @MrPatterns d.p. = decimal places, s.f. = significant figures (d.p. + integer digits)